# Variable in closure

Tags: lambda, lisp, closures, clisp

```
>
(defun hib (f1 f2)
  (cons
    (function
      (lambda ()
        (setq f2 (+ f1 (setq f1 f2))))
    )
    (function
      (lambda ()
        (list 88 f1 f2 99 ))
    )
  )
)
hib
> (setq hib1 (hib 1 1))
(#<function :lambda nil (setq f2 (+ f1 (setq f1 f2)))> .
 #<function :lambda nil (list 88 f1 f2 99)>)
> (setq hib2 (hib 1 1))
(#<function :lambda nil (setq f2 (+ f1 (setq f1 f2)))> .
 #<function :lambda nil (list 88 f1 f2 99)>)
> (funcall (car hib1))
2
> (funcall (car hib1))
3
> (funcall (cdr hib1))
(88 2 3 99)
> (funcall (car hib1))
5
> (funcall (cdr hib1))
(88 3 5 99)
> (funcall (car hib1))
8
> (funcall (cdr hib1))
(88 5 8 99)
> (funcall (car hib2))
2
> (funcall (cdr hib2))
(88 1 2 99)
> (funcall (cdr hib1))
(88 5 8 99)
> (funcall (car hib2))
3
> (funcall (cdr hib2))
(88 2 3 99)
```

Why `(funcall (car hib1))` would change `f1` and `f2` in `(cdr hib1)`?

Why `(funcall (car hib1))` would NOT change `f1` and `f2` in `(cdr hib2)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closures of hib1 and hib2 are different, that is, there are separate
variable bindings.

Calling `(funcall (car hib1))` changes the value of f1 and f2 around the hib1.
Those values are totally different to f1 and f2 around the hib2.

So any number of calls to hib1's environment cannot change hib2's environment.

Comment: But why (funcall (car hib1)) would change f1 and f2 in (cdr hib1)?

Comment: When you call (hib 1 1), LISP implementation generates an environement for that hib, and variables f1 and f2 are kept there. When hib changes the value of f1 and f2, it changes the value of f1 and f2 inside _the_ environment. so `(funcall (car hib1))` change the value of f1 and f2 of it's own enviroment, and cannot change the value of f1 and f2 of other environments.